# Как отсортировать значения в переменных в порядке убывания?

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

Мне нужно отсортировать значения в переменных в порядке убывания, при этом добавив этим переменным имена. К примеру у нас есть два пользователя и нужно пересчитать, сколько сообщений они отправил. Количество этих сообщений хранится в переменных. Вот все, что я смог написать:

```
a_1 = 234
a_2 = 345

a = [a_1, a_2]

a = sorted(a, reverse = True)
print(a)
```

И в итоге у меня выводит это: `[345, 234]`, а мне нужно вывести так: `[User_1: 345, User_2: 234`. Надеюсь, я понятно объяснил. Если что, извините! Я с массивами до этого не работал.

Comment: Разрешите узнать, а откуда там должно взяться User_1 и User_2?

Comment: Я же говорю, что не смог написать больше этого, так как никогда не работал с массивами. Я просто дал пример моих действий. Извините, если задал вопрос некорректно.

Comment: 1 - в python нету массивов, 2 - это списки, 3 - в списках нету никаких ключей или что вы там хотите вывести, есть только индексы 0,1,...n

Comment: Вы можете создать dict и вывести его в таком формате: {"User_1": 345, "User_2": 234}

Comment: Откуда всё-таки должны браться имена пользователей, и как задана их связь с числами?

Answer (score 0):

Приведённый пример `[User_1: 345, User_2: 234]` не является массивом. Массив это последовательность элементов. В данном случае это последовательность пар ключ-значение.

Этому может соответствовать тип dict

```
{'User_1': 345, 'User_2': 234}
```

Либо же массив кортежей

```
[('User_1', 345), ('User_2', 234)]
```

Сам по себе тип `dict` - не упорядоченный, но существует [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) которы сохраняет порядок и, следовательно, может быть отсортирован:

```
# исходные данные
data = {'User_1': 345, 'User_2': 234}
# Сортировка по значению:
orderedData = OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), reverse = True, key = lambda t: t[1]))
```

Тот же подход будет использован в случае с массивом кортежей:

```
# исходные данные
data = [('User_1', 345), ('User_2', 234)]
# Сортировка по значению:
orderedData = sorted(data, reverse = True, key = lambda t: t[1])
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
user1 = 234
user2 = 345
user3 = 545
user4 = 145
user5 = 325
user6 = 15
user7 = 45

a = [user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6, user7]

i=1
new = {}
for f in a:
    name = 'user'+str(i)
    new[name] = f
    i+=1

new = sorted_by_value = sorted(new.items(), key=lambda kv: -kv[1])
print(new)
```